# deleting (POPing) specific elements from list

Tags: python

I am doing book exercise on pop() function in Python (3.5). The instructions are to delete elements from the list using pop(). From the list below, I want to delete n1, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9. Below code works, but very practical) and I don't understand why specific index works only up until [5]. With out using loops (I'm not there yet), what is the proper way of poping specific elements from the list?

```
nameList = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9']
print('I can only invite two people to dinner...')

print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(0).title(), ' will not be invited to 
       dinner') 
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(3).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner')
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(4).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner') 
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(5).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner') 
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(-1).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner')
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(-1).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner')
print('Sorry, but ', nameList.pop(-1).title(), ' will not be invited to
      dinner')
```

Answer (score 2):

The output is:

```
I can only invite two people to dinner...
('Sorry, but ', 'N1', ' will not be invited todinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N5', ' will not be invited to dinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N7', ' will not be invited to dinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N9', ' will not be invited to  dinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N8', ' will not be invited to  dinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N6', ' will not be invited to   dinner')
('Sorry, but ', 'N4', ' will not be invited to   dinner')
```

Lets see it:

At first your list has 9 elements. You remove the first with `pop(0)` so now you have a list with 8 elements namely:

```
['n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9']
```

Not you remove the 3th elelemnt from this 'new' list, which is `n5` (remember indexing starts from 0)

And so on ...

After each remove the list will simply be shorter, so even after the first remove there won be an element at the eighth position to remove (this happens after pop(5) in your case).

There is no 'general' way of removing elements from a list, but note that lists are mutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the length of nameList changes dynamically every time you use 'pop'.
So after you pop 4 elements(n1,n4,n5,n6), there are only 5 elements left in nameList. 
You can not use pop(5) anymore because the index is out of range at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Specific index works like a charm for all indices **up to the size of your list**. The problem you're running into here is that when you remove an element from a list, you shrink it, the size is reduced by 1 every time you pop.

Say you have a list of 3 elements, `l = ["a","b","c"]`
You pop the first one `l.pop(0)`, that will return `"a"` but it will also modify the list so that now `l` is equal to `["b","c"]`.
If, instead, you had popped the last item with `l.pop(2)` or `l.pop(-1)` (because Python lets you count elements from the last one as well, so -1 is always the last element of the list), you would have gotten `"c"` and the list `l` would have become `["a","b"]`.
Notice that in both cases, the list has shrunk and has only two elements left, so you will not be able to pop the element number `2` now, since there is no such thing.

If you want to read an element instead of removing it from the list, use the `myList[elementIndex]` syntax. For instance, in your example, `nameList[6]` will return `"n7"` but it will not modify the list at all.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your list length changes every time you pop an element from the list. So if you want to use `pop` specifically, to remove the specified elements an easy and tricky way would be the following:

```
>>> nameList = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9']
>>>
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n1'))
'n1'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n4'))
'n4'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n5'))
'n5'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n6'))
'n6'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n7'))
'n7'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n8'))
'n8'
>>> nameList.pop(nameList.index('n9'))
'n9'
>>> nameList
['n2', 'n3']
```

So as you can see every time we pop an element we specify its `index` so we don't have a problem that the list length changes - cause using `index` we will get the new index of the element! And as you can see the result will be: `['n2', 'n3']` as expected!